# Image resize differently on phone vs. tablet?

Tags: css, wordpress, resize

I'm working on a Wordpress site where I have a background image that serves as my logo and my actual header image is transparent. I'm using this code to resize the background image for mobile:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
body.custom-background {
    background-image: url(http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/backgroundlogo2.jpg);
    background-position: 50% top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: 70% auto;
}
```

}

The problem I'm having is that it looks good on a tablet but is too small on a phone. I'd like it to be wider on phone only and there is a bunch of empty space below it. I think the space may have to do with my header image needing to be resized too.

Is there a way to resize the transparent header image too, but only on a phone, not tablet? And is there a way to resize this background image differently on a phone vs. tablet? That code sets it to 70%, which is great on the tablet, but I'd prefer larger on a phone.

You can [view my website here](http://www.gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/) if needed. This is my first time working with a mobile layout. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line:

```
background-size: 70% auto;
```

it looks fine for me on all size screens.

It's the 70% that is shrinking that image - display using 70% of the width of the screen. The line:

```
background-position: 50% top;
```

keeps the image centred and at the top of the page. When you remove the `background-size` the image remains at full size and centred, which I think looks fine on mobile. It just starts to clip the sides of the image, but the text of the logo isn't affected.

To prevent the logo being clipped, we need a bit more thought. At a width of 640px and using the 70% rule, the background image appears almost exactly full size at 450px. So we need two rules:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    body.custom-background {
        background-size: auto;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    body.custom-background {
        background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

That means, between 450px and 640px, the background will appear at it's original size - 450px. Then, when the screen is smaller than 450px, it is contained, so shrinks to 100% the screen width. Now, on those smaller screens, the background image is either the original image size, or the full width of the screen - it will no longer get cut off.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that! I tried it out and I just don't like the image being cut off on the sides. If it was just a little bit, I wouldn't mind but it's kind of a lot :(

Comment: No problem - the image itself if 450px wide. So you could create a special rule just for that background image on screens smaller than 640px (using the 70% rule, 640px is about where the image displays at exactly 450px wide) - I will add code to my answer

Comment: That looks great!! Thank you so much! This is all new to me. I don't know if I ever would have figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

@media (max-width: 480px){
  add here your CSS for phones
}

Answer (score 0):

Pictures on you website will be change when with width bellow 420px. So, add this rule to the background image maybe a good idea.

```
@media (max-width: 420px)
body.custom-background {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: This works for the phone but if I do this, it messes up the way it looks on the tablet. :(